# SQL command stuck for only one table in postgres

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql

SQL command stuck for only one table in postgres

I am working in django project which use **postgres** database.

SQL query working for all tables but not working on `common_designprofilecontent` table

**Working**:

```
reader=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  common_document;
 count 
-------
 20046
(1 row)
```

**Not working**:

```
reader=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  common_designprofilecontent;
```

No result from this query, minimum 20046 * 4 row present in this table.

---

After doing following:

```
reader=# select * from pg_stat_activity;

5:30 | 2016-03-21 10:22:27.240863+05:30 | 2016-03-21 10:22:28.614431+05:30 | t       | SELECT "common_designprofilecontent"."id", "common_designprofil
econtent"."page_id", "common_designprofilecontent"."doc_id", "common_designprofilecontent"."profilename", "common_designprofilecontent"."profileconten
t", "common_designprofilecontent"."page_rev_no", "common_designprofilecontent"."createdDate", "common_designprofilecontent"."createdAgent_id", "common
_designprofilecontent"."modifiedDate", "common_designprofilecontent"."modifiedAgent_id" FROM "common_designprofilecontent" WHERE "common_designprofile
content"."doc_id" = 26952 
 16440 | reader        |   28783 |       10 | postgres | vacuumdb         |             |                 |          -1 | 2016-03-19 23:37:15.579589+0
5:30 | 2016-03-19 23:37:15.581737+05:30 | 2016-03-19 23:37:15.581737+05:30 | t       | VACUUM (FULL, ANALYZE);                                        



                                   +
```

Also nothing come in log file `/var/log/pgsql`

Comment: What do you mean by no result? Hanging? Just empty result? And there's a full vacuum running for some reason, that might block things.

Comment: If you restart postgres can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: Hanging.. I do not know about vacuum.

Comment: @spicyramen: I restarted postgres, nut still same issue.

Comment: @spicyramen ad Sami: Now working. But do not know, how :)
Thanx. :)

Comment: Please close this question. No point in "do not know how" questions lingering around here on SO.

Comment: @Patrick: Yes I voted for Closed request.

Answer (score 0):

Django can be tricky with big tables, I have tried raw SQL queries and they seem to not work well on django. I think the easiest and fastest option for you will be to use count

```
x = pg_stat_activity.objects.all()
x.count()
```

or

```
len(x)
```

len is faster...